Invalid JWT Signature When Integrating Zoom SDK in React and Node.js
I'm trying to integrate the Zoom Meeting SDK into my React application using a Node.js backend to generate the JWT signature. Despite using the correct credentials and following the official documentation, I keep encountering an "Invalid Signature" error. I've also tested the JWT on jwt.io and it shows an invalid signature.
Environment Details:
Node.js version: V20.16.0
Zoom SDK version: @zoom/meetingsdk 3.8.5
React version: 18.2.0
ServerSide Code :
import cors from 'cors';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import express from 'express';
import { KJUR } from 'jsrsasign';
import { inNumberArray, isBetween, isRequiredAllOrNone, validateRequest } from './validations.js';

dotenv.config();
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.use(express.json(), cors());
app.options('*', cors());

const propValidations = {
  role: inNumberArray([0, 1]),
  expirationSeconds: isBetween(1800, 172800)
};

const schemaValidations = [isRequiredAllOrNone(['meetingNumber', 'role'])];

const coerceRequestBody = (body) => ({
  ...body,
  ...['role', 'expirationSeconds'].reduce(
    (acc, cur) => ({ ...acc, [cur]: typeof body[cur] === 'string' ? parseInt(body[cur]) : body[cur] }),
    {}
  )
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  const requestBody = coerceRequestBody(req.body);
  const validationErrors = validateRequest(requestBody, propValidations, schemaValidations);

  if (validationErrors.length > 0) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: validationErrors });
  }

  const { meetingNumber, role, expirationSeconds } = requestBody;
  const iat = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) - 30;
  const exp = iat + 60 * 60 * 2;
  const oHeader = { alg: 'HS256', typ: 'JWT' };

  const oPayload = {
    sdkKey: process.env.ZOOM_MEETING_SDK_KEY,
    mn: meetingNumber,
    role,
    iat,
    exp,
    tokenExp: exp
  };

  const sHeader = JSON.stringify(oHeader);
  const sPayload = JSON.stringify(oPayload);
  const sdkJWT = KJUR.jws.JWS.sign('HS256', sHeader, sPayload, process.env.ZOOM_MEETING_SDK_SECRET);
  return res.json({ signature: sdkJWT });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Zoom Meeting SDK Auth Endpoint Sample Node.js, listening on port ${port}!`));

FrontEnd Code
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { ZoomMtg } from '@zoom/meetingsdk';

ZoomMtg.preLoadWasm();
ZoomMtg.prepareWebSDK();

function App() {
  var authEndpoint = 'http://localhost:4000';
  var sdkKey = 'sdkKey';
  var meetingNumber = 'meetingNumber';
  var passWord = 'passWord';
  var role = 0;
  var userName = 'userName';
  var userEmail = 'userEmail';
  var registrantToken = '';
  var zakToken = '';
  var leaveUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';

  function getSignature(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch(authEndpoint, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        meetingNumber: meetingNumber,
        role: role
      })
    }).then(res => res.json())
    .then(response => {
      startMeeting(response.signature);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }

  function startMeeting(signature) {
    document.getElementById('zmmtg-root').style.display = 'block';

    ZoomMtg.init({
      leaveUrl: leaveUrl,
      patchJsMedia: true,
      leaveOnPageUnload: true,
      success: (success) => {
        console.log(success);

        ZoomMtg.join({
          signature: signature,
          sdkKey: sdkKey,
          meetingNumber: meetingNumber,
          passWord: passWord,
          userName: userName,
          userEmail: userEmail,
          tk: registrantToken,
          zak: zakToken,
          success: (success) => {
            console.log(success);
          },
          error: (error) => {
            console.log(error);
          }
        });

      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <main>
        <h1>Zoom Meeting SDK Sample React</h1>
        <button onClick={getSignature}>Join Meeting</button>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

